# How can I make multiple commands with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to make a script that will open up tmux and then split the screens and open up a few python instances but it will ony run the first command.

```
k   = PyKeyboard()

def cntrl_b(key):
    k.press_key('Control_L')
    k.tap_key('b')
    k.release_key('Control_L')
    k.tap_key(key)

def make_win():
    subprocess.call('tmux')
    subprocess.call(cntrl_b('%'))
    subprocess.call('clear')
    subprocess.call('"')
    subprocess.call('clear')
    subprocess.call('ipython')
    subprocess.call(cntrl_b('o'))
    subprocess.call('bpython')

if __name__=='__main__':
    make_win()
```

I'm calling 'clear' because I'm using powerline and I get error messages when I open tmux.

I've tested each command individually and they each work.

This code will just open tmux and not do any of the other commands.

Comment: You might want to check out a tool called tmuxinator that can be used to start multiple tmux sessions and send commands to them. I belive tmuxinator works by sending keystrokes to the parent terminal, not to individual shell sessions.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks for the to tip, I've been having a play around with it, it seems fun.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs 'tmux' and waits for it to exit.  After tmux has exited, your program calls your function `cntrl_b` which will return `None`.  That return value is used as the path of the next program to run when you pass it to `subprocess.call()`.  This is clearly not what you want.

What you want is to run the tmux process, then send input to it.  Something like this:

```
def make_win():
    proc = subprocess.Popen('tmux', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    # TODO: look up the bytes for Ctrl+B and put that in the string
    proc.stdin.write('Bo'); proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.write('clear\n'); proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.write('"'); proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.write('clear\n'); proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.write('ipython\n'); proc.stdin.flush()
    # TODO: look up the bytes for Ctrl+B and put that in the string
    proc.stdin.write('Bo'); proc.stdin.flush()
    proc.stdin.write('bpython\n'); proc.stdin.flush()
```